# Why can't request a large static file(more than 150KB) which cause the page load very very slo

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery-ui

I have a website need to deploy to customer box, but there is an odd problem that some pages load very slowly, both IE and Chrome have the same problem.  Open the developer tool and noticed that the request 'jquery-ui.min.js' need more that 2 minutes and it blocks other requests, and also there is an error 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET' on this request.

I never meet this problem on my local and also can not reproduce even I have tried to change many IIS settings.

This .js file is the biggest one(233KB), So I suspect this .js file is block or truncates by the firewall or IIS setting , maybe the file size is more than the maximum, I am not sure, but the customer said no firewall in their enviorment.

After Prepared some different size JS files and test on customer box, the response is success when request the file(107KB) and failed  when request the file(183KB), I am start to believe my guess.

So, based the request, my current workaround is --divides the large JS file into several smaller one and make sure their size is less than 100 KB, 
Now, it works well on customer environment and slowness problem has solved.

However, I'm dying to know what caused it ? I need to know which limit the response size, as we all know, this limitation will affect a lot on UI.
Any one who knows?  thanks very much

Screenshot of the error:
[image: screenshot of the error]

Screenshot of the request time line:
[image: screenshot of the request time line]

Comment: Does it need more than 2 minutes on local tests?

Comment: no, the load time is very normal on my local.

Comment: noticed another  guy have been tortured by this issue on http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/34525/page-taking-too-long-to-load-due-to-error-jquery-ui-1103customminjs.aspx#171513

Comment: There is something odd in these screenshots. The transfer size / file size in the timed out / conn-reset request is identical to when it succeeds. I'm curious if this goes away per @JosephCharnin 's answer but I'd be wary that this doesn't affect other things hosted on the same server in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading it from Google:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, but it's an internal website, we don't want to request an external resource.

Comment: @qianchaopan that's fair enough but in the interest of identifying the problem could you please try this and see if it works?

Comment: OK, I will have a try later.

Answer (score -2):

How about using wireshark to see what actually happens? This might show you if the bottleneck is on the network.

Comment: thanks Mathieu, It's on the customer machine and can not reproduce on my local, it's an intranet APP, I don't know whether I can install such software but I think it's impolite.